# python dictionary keyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

New to python and what looks like simple doable piece of code yielding `KeyError`:

```
patt=list('jkasb')

dict={}
for i in patt:
    dict[i]= 1 if dict[i] is None else dict[i]+1 # This line throws error
```

> error: KeyError: 'j'

Comment: `if dict[i] is None` raises an error because there is no `dict[i]` yet.

Comment: Also, don't give your variables the name of builtin functions (like `dict`, here)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case, the KeyError is occurring because you are trying to access a key which is not in the dictionary. Initially, the dictionary is empty. So, none of the keys exist in it.

This may seem strange if you are coming from a C++ background as C++ maps give default values for keys that don't exist yet. You can get the same behavior in python by using `collections.defaultdict`. The modified code is given below. I took the liberty of converting the defaultdict to a regular dictionary at the end of the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
patt='jkasb'

my_default_dict=defaultdict(int)
for i in patt:
    my_default_dict[i]+=1

my_dict = dict(my_default_dict) # converting the defaultdict to a regular dictionary
```

You can also solve this problem in a number of other ways. I am showing some of them below:

- **By checking if the key exists in the dictionary:**

  ```
  patt='jkasb'

  my_dict={}
  for i in patt:
      my_dict[i]= 1 if i not in my_dict else my_dict[i]+1 # checking if i exists in dict
  ```
- **Using `dict.get()` without default return values:**

  ```
  patt='jkasb'

  my_dict={}
  for i in patt:
      my_dict[i]= 1 if my_dict.get(i) is None else my_dict[i]+1 # using dict.get
  print(my_dict)
  ```
- **Using `dict.get()` with default return values:**

  ```
  patt='jkasb'

  my_dict={}
  for i in patt:
      my_dict[i]= my_dict.get(i, 0)+1 # using dict.get with default return value 0
  ```
- **As your code is actually just counting the frequency of each character, you can also use `collections.Counter` and then convert it to a dictionary:**

  ```
  from collections import Counter
  patt='jkasb'

  character_counter = Counter(patt)

  my_dict = dict(character_counter)
  ```

Also, as dict is a built-in data type and I used dict to convert the defaultdict and Counter to a normal dictionary, I changed the name of the dictionary from dict to my_dict.

Answer (score 6):

While building the dict `dict`, `dict[i]` is trying to access a key which does not exist yet, in order to check if a key exists in a dictionary, use the `in` operator instead:

```
d[i] = 1 if i not in d else d[i] + 1
```

Alternatives (for what you're trying to accomplish):

#### Using [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
```

#### Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for i in 'jkasb':
    d[i] += 1
```

#### Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter('jkasb')
```

Avoid using `dict` (built-in type) as a variable name. And just iterate over `'jkasb'` without having to convert it to a list, strings are iterable too.

Answer (score 3):

As your `dict` is initially empty, trying to access any value with `dict[i]` will throw a `KeyError`.

You should replace this with [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which returns `None` if the key is not found:

```
for i in patt:
    dict[i] = 1 if dict.get(i) is None else dict[i] + 1
```

Another alternative, as suggested by @snakecharmerb, is to check beforehand whether or not the key exists in your dict:

```
for i in patt:
    dict[i] = 1 if i not in dict else dict[i] + 1
```

Both solutions are equivalent, but the second is maybe more "idiomatic".

Comment: or simply `dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1`

Comment: got it. Dint know they made dict[] and dict.get to have different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

These snippets: `dict[i]` and`dict[i]+1` will try to get a value from the dictionary with the corresponding key `i`.  Since you have nothing in your dictionary, you get a KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access a key in an empty dictionary, you can also use [defaultdic](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html) so you do not care if the key exists already or not:

```
from collections import defaultdict

patt=list('jkasb')

my_dict = defaultdict(int) 
for i in patt:
   my_dict[i] += 1
```