# Convert nested dictionary inside dictionary into relational and add missing keys using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, keyerror

I am trying to convert below json records into relational but I am not getting the expected output,

Filename.json:-

```
{
   "SampleRecord":{
      "SampleRules":[
         {
            "Scaler_id":"1",
            "family_min_samples_percentage":5,
            "original_number_of_clusters":4,
            "Results":[
               {
                  "eps_value":0.1,
                  "min_samples":5,
                  "number_of_clusters":9,
                  "number_of_noise_samples":72,
                  "scores":{
                     "adjusted_rand_index":0.001,
                     "adjusted_mutual_info_score":0.009
                  }
               }
            ],
            "isnegative":"False",
            "comment":[
               "@Comment"
            ],
            "enable":"enabled",
            "additional_value":{
               "type":[
                  {
                     "value":"AAA"
                  }
               ],
               "uid":[
                  {
                     "value":"BBB"
                  }
               ],
               "options":[
                  {
                     "value":"CCC"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"DDD"
                  }
               ],
               "scope":[
                  {
                     "value":"EEE"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "Scaler_id":"2",
            "family_min_samples_percentage":5,
            "original_number_of_clusters":4,
            "Results":[
               {
                  "eps_value":0.1,
                  "min_samples":5,
                  "number_of_clusters":9,
                  "number_of_noise_samples":72,
                  "scores":{
                     "adjusted_rand_index":0.001,
                     "adjusted_mutual_info_score":0.009
                  }
               }
            ],
            "isnegative":"False",
            "comment":[
               "@Comment"
            ],
            "enable":"enabled",
            "additional_value":{
               "type":[
                  {
                     "value":"AAA"
                  }
               ],
               "uid":[
                  {
                     "value":"BBB"
                  }
               ],
               "options":[
                  {
                     "value":"CCC"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
Scaler_id~original_number_of_clusters~Results_eps_value~Results_Scores_adjusted_rand_index~Results_Scores_avies_bouldin_score~isnegative~comment~additional_value_type~additional_value_uid~additional_value_options
1~4~0.1~0.001~1.70~False~@comment~AAA~BBB~CCC~EEE
1~4~0.1~0.001~1.70~False~@comment~AAA~BBB~DDD~EEE
2~4~0.1~0.001~1.70~False~@comment~AAA~BBB~CCC~Null
```

```
with open(Filename.json) as inputfile:
   content = inputfile.read()
   data=json.loads(json.dumps(content,ensure_ascii=False))
df1=pd.json_normalize(data['SampleRecord'],'SampleRules',sep='_')
df23.to_csv('Sample1.txt',encoding='utf-8',index=False,sep'~',na_rep='')
```

**output(Sample1.txt):**

```
Scaler_id~original_number_of_clusters~Results~isnegative~comment~additional_value_type~additional_value_uid~additional_value_options

1~4~[{0.1},{0.001},{1.70}]~False~@comment~[{AAA}]~[{BBB}]~[{CCC},{DDD}]~[{EEE}]
2~4~[{0.1},{0.001},{1.70}]~False~@comment~[{AAA}]~[{BBB}]~[{CCC}]~
```

```
    df2=pd.json_normalize(data['SampleRecord'],['SampleRules','Results'],[['SampleRules','Scaler_id'],['SampleRules','original_number_of_clusters'],['SampleRules','isnegative'],['SampleRules','comment']],record_prefix='Results',sep='_',max_level=None,errors='ignore')
        df3=pd.json_normalize(data['SampleRecord'],['SampleRules','additional_value','type'],['SampleRules','Scaler_id'],record_prefix='additional_value',sep='_',max_level=None,errors='ignore') 
        df23=pd.merge(df2,df3,how='inner',left_on=('SampleRules_Scaler_id'),right_on=('SampleRules_Scaler_id'))
        df23.to_csv('Sample2.txt',encoding='utf-8',index=False,sep'~',na_rep='')
```

**Current output(Sample2.txt):**

```
    1~4~0.1~0.001~1.70~False~@comment~AAA~BBB~CCC
    1~4~0.1~0.001~1.70~False~@comment~AAA~BBB~DDD
    2~4~0.1~0.001~1.70~False~@comment~AAA~BBB~CCC
```

```
    df4=pd.json_normalize(data['SampleRecord'],['SampleRules','additional_value','scope'],['SampleRules','Scaler_id'],record_prefix='additional_value',sep='_',max_level=None,errors='ignore')   #This throws KeyError='Scope' (since this key is missing in few records)

I tried to use get() since it gives default value None but it didnt work,

    df4=pd.json_normalize(data['SampleRecord']['SampleRules'],['additional_value'],['scope'].get('value'),['SampleRules','Scaler_id'],record_prefix='additional_value',sep='_',max_level=None,errors='ignore')

#TypeError : list indices must be integers or slices,not str
```

**Problems:**

1)How to get nested dictionary (additional_value) values in single normalize python code like without explicitly defining df2,df3,df4 for each sub dictionaries?

2)How to get missing key as Null if key itself missing in Json record and avoid keyError

I have already referred the below,but no luck

[How to fill missing json keys with key and null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929579/how-to-fill-missing-json-keys-with-key-and-null-value)

[If key not in JSON then set value to null and insert into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010582/if-key-not-in-json-then-set-value-to-null-and-insert-into-dataframe)

[Python JSON TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591062/python-json-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

[python dictionary keyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747406/python-dictionary-keyerror)

I am a beginner to Python. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Filename.json is neither valid json nor valid python.

Comment: I've re-formatted & updated the valid json.